# How to make a URI which passes two parameters using restlet : Restlet 2.1

Tags: restlet

This is an example of a method:

updatePatientAddressByID(String ID, String address)

Any Help

Comment: Please do not cross-post with the Restlet mailing list... http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=2951260

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your URL so that the Id is a path segment :

```
router.attach("/patients/{id}", PatientResource.class);
```

Then in your Restlet implementation, you can get this variable :

```
@Post
public void store(String address) {
    Long id = (Long) getRequest().getAttributes().get("id");
    ... do something with address ...
}
```

Comment: every resource can accept each HTTP method at most ... this will depend on the structure of your resources...

Comment: Do I have to make a separate resource class for it??

Because I already have a class which contains a method for addPatient..

Another question If I have a patient resource class which contains 4 methods: 1. AddPatient (Patient p) 2. DeletePatient (String ID) 3. RetrievePatient(String ID) 4.UpdatePatientAddress(String ID, String Address)

Can I implement them in one resource class, if so how could I perform the server-side routing??

Thanks in advance, you are saving me....